# Complex XPath axes/where (BizTalk EDI 856 Schema)

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

The requirement is to find the value of the MAN02 segment in the HL1Loop that has HL03='P' and HL01='3' (in a file that potentially have dozens of HL1Loops, but I have included just a couple for purposes of reproducing the question.)

I got this much working:

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1'][.//*[HL03='P'] and .//*[HL01='3']]
```

will return the desired HLLoop1 (with sample data below). I have a reason for getting that specific item, much too lengthy to explain here (parsing a Microsoft BizTalk schema that represents an 856 EDI advance ship notice document). There might be other HLLoop1's that also have "MAN02" in them, and this is the one I need.

Now I want to return just the MAN02 value. 
Tried this, but it's a no-go:

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1']//MAN/MAN02[.//*[HL03='P'] and .//*[HL01='3']]
```

Would I need to add more prefixes to get the HL03 to go back a few nodes, something like this?

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1']//MAN/MAN02[.//.//.//*[HL03='P'] and .//.//.//*[HL01='3']]
```

or would I add something on the end like this:

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1'][.//*[HL03='P'] and .//*[HL01='3']]//*MAN02
```

This give "extra illegal tokens", and I think maybe adding more brackets in the right places would fix it.

I know it's a matter of getting the axes and the "where clause" straight.

Example here: 
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/3005df62b369fd0fff86e7b3e492a377

Data

```
<ns0:X12_00401_856 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL01>2</HL01>
            <HL02>1</HL02>
            <HL03>O</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
        <ns0:PRF>
            <PRF01>287775</PRF01>
        </ns0:PRF>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL01>3</HL01>
            <HL02>2</HL02>
            <HL03>P</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
        <ns0:MAN>
            <MAN01>CP</MAN01>
            <MAN02>465467995515</MAN02>
        </ns0:MAN>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
</ns0:X12_00401_856>
```

I will be using it XSLT, something like this:

```
      <LineItemCarrierTrackingNum>
           <xsl:variable name="currentHL02" select="HL02" /> 
           <xsl:value-of select="concat("//*[local-name()='HLLoop1'][.//*[HL03='O'] and ..//*[HL01='", $currentHL02,"']]//*MAN02";  /> 
      </LineItemCarrierTrackingNum>
```

I'm hoping I can build the XPath as a variable as shown above...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT (and even if not), you should avoid using `/*[local-name()='..']` which can select more than you intend (not to mention being unreadable). Note also that using an explicit path is more efficient than the descendant axis.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:X12_00401_856">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HLLoop1[ns0:HL/HL01='3' and ns0:HL/HL03='P']/ns0:MAN/MAN02"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>465467995515</result>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just posted my alternative solution.  About to try in XSLT, but the value of HL02 will be a variable - based on where I'm currently looping through the xml in a bigger for-each.

Comment: I don't see where that value of `HL02` plays a role here.

Comment: See my response to Michael Kay, the real world application is obviously much more difficult...  I'm in a <xsl:for-each select="//s0:HLLoop1[s0:HL/HL03='I']">

Comment: I can only answer the question you asked. If you're in a different context, then the question is radically different -- Note also that if you're processing only  `HLLoop1` nodes where `ns0:HL/HL03='I'` then the predicate `ns0:HL/HL03='P'` will NEVER be true.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is to use the expression `//MAN02`.

OK, that's probably not the answer you want; but if that's the case, it's because you haven't explained the real problem.

Getting data using XPath from a single input document is generally trivial; the problem arises when you want to construct an expression that will also work with other documents (that is, with documents that vary in some way from the initial test case). So you need to explain what the invariants are: what parts of your specimen document are reliable characteristics of the general class of documents, and what parts are incidental? If all your documents contain a single MAN02 element like your example document does, then retrieving the MAN02 element is dead easy.

Comment: I'm working the Microsoft BizTalk schema for the EDI 856 document. The HLLoop1 allows for packages within packages (example packages, pallettes, railcars etc...), would take a page to explain.  So I'm looping through the HL1Loops where HL03 = "I" - the line items, and I need to go back up the hierarchy to get the corresponding HL1Loop.  I alluded to this in my XSLT fragment, that I want to use my current HL02 value to lookup the corresponding HL01.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't expect us to work out your requirements by showing us code that doesn't meet them.

Comment: I'm not asking for requirements review.  The requirement is to find the value of the MAN02 segment in the HL1Loop that has HL03='P' and HL01='3' (in a file that potentially have dozens of HL1Loops.  I didn't think it was necessary to include more than the minimum to reproduce the issue.   If I can get the correct XPath for that, I can continue on my merry way.

Comment: I think I found my solution, posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it, but would like to know if there was any better approach.

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1'][//*[HL03='P'] and //*[HL01='3']]//MAN02
```

This was one of the options I had in my original question, but needed //MAN02 instead of //*MAN02.  Got the other way working too, but agree with the comment that it's too obtuse:

```
//*[local-name()='HLLoop1']//MAN02[..//..//*[HL03='P'] and ..//..//*[HL01='3']]
```

Sometimes, you have to rest for a night, and get a new view on the problem. 
Issues with my previous attempts:

1) MAN had a namespace, so just skipped //MAN02

2) I was using .// instead of ..// (one dot is self, and two dots is parent). 
Since I have found MAN02, I have to go up two parents (one parent takes mae back to MAN, and another parent takes me back to HLLOOP1).

Now I need to try the variable in XSLT an see if it works from there.

Comment: This is (among other things) unnecessary complicated. The conditions apply to `HLLoop1` that is "on the way" to MAN02. That's where that should be expressed, not by going back upwards in the tree.

Comment: Agreed, updated.  I cannot get the s0:HLLoop1 working in BizTalk, but that would be another issue/question.